# Static class "Fields" in google analytics v3

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement google analytics v3 in my app following the google developers example, and in the example it uses the following command:

```
MyApp.getGaTracker().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, SCREEN_LABEL);
```

I just want to know what the hell is "Fields"? I guess it's a static class, but I can't find any reference.
Sorry if I'm being a little ignorant, but I just can't find. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Luiz, V3 is legacy. You should use the latest SDK they have.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android

Comment: When you add a Custom Dimension in Google Analytics they use the Fields class in their example.